# Unable to load the kernel image of imx8 device

Tags: boot, kernel, snap, ubuntu-core

I have created Ubuntu core image using Kernel snap and gadget snap using snap craft , after flashing the generated image in sd card and connecting the sd card into the ***iMX8MP-EVK*** board the board is booting successfully till the U-boot but after loading the kernel image its throwing an error and stops loading the kernel image.
Please help me to find the solution for this. Please find below the logs.

```
Run CMD11 1.8V switch switch to partitions #0, OK mmc1 is current device Run CMD11 1.8V switch 28092928 bytes read in 556 ms (48.2 MiB/s) Booting from mmc ... 60128 bytes read in 79 ms (743.2 KiB/s)
## Flattened Device Tree blob at 43000000    Booting using the fdt blob at 0x43000000    Using Device Tree in place at 0000000043000000, end 0000000043011adf Can't find cec device id=0x3c fail to probe panel device adv7535@3d fail to get display timings probe video device failed, ret -19

Starting kernel ...

[    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0000000000 [0x410fd034] [    0.000000] Linux version 5.4.24-gbabac008e (kuldeep@kuldeep-HP-ENVY-Notebook) (gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu
9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04)) #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Sep 21 16:13:29 IST 2021 [    0.000000] Machine model: NXP i.MX8MPlus EVK board [    0.000000] efi: Getting EFI parameters from FDT: [    0.000000] efi: UEFI not found. [
0.000000] Reserved memory: created CMA memory pool at 0x00000000c4000000, size 960 MiB [    0.000000] OF: reserved mem: initialized node linux,cma, compatible id shared-dma-pool [   
0.000000] NUMA: No NUMA configuration found [    0.000000] NUMA: Faking a node at [mem 0x0000000040000000-0x00000001bfffffff] [   
0.000000] NUMA: NODE_DATA [mem 0x1bf3c6500-0x1bf3c7fff] [    0.000000] Zone ranges: [    0.000000]   DMA32    [mem 0x0000000040000000-0x00000000ffffffff] [    0.000000]   Normal   [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x00000001bfffffff] [    0.000000] Movable zone start for each node [    0.000000] Early memory node ranges [   
0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000040000000-0x00000000557fffff] [    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000056000000-0x00000000923fffff] [    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000094400000-0x00000001bfffffff] [    0.000000] Initmem setup node 0 [mem 0x0000000040000000-0x00000001bfffffff] [    0.000000] psci: probing for conduit method from DT. [    0.000000] psci: PSCIv1.1 detected in firmware. [    0.000000] psci: Using standard PSCI v0.2 function IDs [
0.000000] psci: MIGRATE_INFO_TYPE not supported. [    0.000000] psci: SMC Calling Convention v1.1 [    0.000000] percpu: Embedded 24 pages/cpu s58904 r8192 d31208 u98304 [    0.000000] Detected VIPT I-cache on CPU0 [    0.000000] CPU features: detected: ARM erratum 845719 [    0.000000] CPU features: detected: GIC system register CPU interface [    0.000000] Speculative Store Bypass Disable mitigation not required [    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 1538048 [    0.000000] Policy zone: Normal [    0.000000] Kernel command line: console=ttymxc1,115200 root=/dev/mmcblk1p2 rootwait rw [    0.000000] Dentry cache hash table entries: 1048576 (order: 11, 8388608 bytes, linear) [    0.000000] Inode-cache hash table entries: 524288 (order: 10, 4194304 bytes, linear) [   
0.000000] mem auto-init: stack:off, heap alloc:off, heap free:off [    0.000000] software IO TLB: mapped [mem 0xc0000000-0xc4000000] (64MB) [    0.000000] Memory: 5049504K/6250496K available (16508K kernel code, 1450K rwdata, 6480K rodata, 2944K init, 1015K bss, 217952K reserved, 983040K cma-reserved) [    0.000000] SLUB: HWalign=64, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=4, Nodes=1 [    0.000000] rcu: Preemptible hierarchical RCU implementation. [    0.000000] rcu:     RCU restricting CPUs from NR_CPUS=256 to nr_cpu_ids=4. [    0.000000]  Tasks RCU enabled. [    0.000000] rcu: RCU calculated value of scheduler-enlistment delay is 25 jiffies. [    0.000000] rcu: Adjusting geometry for rcu_fanout_leaf=16, nr_cpu_ids=4 [    0.000000] NR_IRQS: 64, nr_irqs: 64, preallocated irqs: 0 [    0.000000] GICv3: GIC: Using split EOI/Deactivate mode [    0.000000] GICv3: 160 SPIs implemented [    0.000000] GICv3: 0 Extended SPIs implemented [   
0.000000] GICv3: Distributor has no Range Selector support [    0.000000] GICv3: 16 PPIs implemented [    0.000000] GICv3: no VLPI support, no direct LPI support [    0.000000] GICv3: CPU0: found redistributor 0 region 0:0x0000000038880000 [    0.000000] ITS: No ITS available, not enabling LPIs [    0.000000] irq-imx-gpcv2: EL3 does not support FSL_SIP_CONFIG_GPC_CORE_WAKE, disabling cpuidle. 
0.243045] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized [    0.243859] clocksource: Switched to clocksource arch_sys_counter [    0.244000] VFS: Disk quotas dquot_6.6.0 [    0.244050] VFS: Dquot-cache hash table entries: 512 (order 0, 4096 bytes) [    0.244198] pnp: PnP ACPI: disabled [    0.249808] thermal_sys: Registered thermal governor 'step_wise' [    0.249811] thermal_sys: Registered thermal governor 'power_allocator' [    0.250175] NET: Registered protocol family 2 [  
0.250462] tcp_listen_portaddr_hash hash table entries: 4096 (order: 4, 65536 bytes, linear) [    0.250543] TCP established hash table entries: 65536 (order: 7, 524288 bytes, linear) [    0.250949] TCP bind hash table entries: 65536 (order: 8, 1048576 bytes, linear) [   
0.251798] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 65536 bind 65536) [    0.251965] UDP hash table entries: 4096 (order: 5, 131072 bytes, linear) [    0.252109] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 4096 (order: 5, 131072 bytes, linear) [    0.252364] NET: Registered protocol family 1 [    0.252678] RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module. [  
0.252683] RPC: Registered udp transport module. [    0.252688] RPC: Registered tcp transport module. [    0.252694] RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module. [    0.253032] PCI: CLS 0 bytes, default 64 [    0.253663] hw perfevents: enabled with armv8_pmuv3 PMU driver, 7 counters available [    0.254088] kvm [1]: IPA Size Limit: 40bits [    0.254989] kvm [1]: GICv3: no GICV resource entry [   
0.254994] kvm [1]: disabling GICv2 emulation [    0.255011] kvm [1]: GIC system register CPU interface enabled [    0.255064] kvm [1]: vgic interrupt IRQ1 [    0.255141] kvm [1]: Hyp mode initialized successfully [    0.260175] Initialise system trusted keyrings [   
0.260281] workingset: timestamp_bits=44 max_order=21 bucket_order=0 [    0.266483] squashfs: version 4.0 (2009/01/31) Phillip Lougher [    0.267090] NFS: Registering the id_resolver key type [    0.267109] Key type id_resolver registered [    0.267115] Key type id_legacy registered [    0.267124] nfs4filelayout_init: NFSv4 File Layout Driver Registering... [    0.267141] jffs2: version 2.2. (NAND) © 2001-2006 Red Hat, Inc. [    0.267481] 9p: Installing v9fs 9p2000 file system support [    0.280242] Key type asymmetric registered [   
0.280248] Asymmetric key parser 'x509' registered [    0.280277] Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 244) [   
0.280355] io scheduler mq-deadline registered [    0.280360] io scheduler kyber registered [    0.282648] samsung-hdmi-phy 32fdff00.hdmiphy: failed to get phy apb clk [    0.286733] pwm-backlight lvds_backlight: lvds_backlight supply power not found, using dummy regulator [    0.287271] EINJ: ACPI disabled. [   
0.293706] i.MX8MP clock driver probe done [    0.297571] imx-sdma 30bd0000.dma-controller: Direct firmware load for imx/sdma/sdma-imx7d.bin failed with error -2 [    0.297583] imx-sdma 30bd0000.dma-controller: Falling back to sysfs fallback for: imx/sdma/sdma-imx7d.bin [    0.299336] mxs-dma 33000000.dma-apbh: initialized [    0.300887] Bus freq driver module loaded [   
0.306902] Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 4 ports, IRQ sharing enabled [    0.309332] 30860000.serial: ttymxc0 at MMIO 0x30860000 (irq = 29, base_baud = 5000000) is a IMX [    0.309794] 30880000.serial: ttymxc2 at MMIO 0x30880000 (irq = 30, base_baud = 5000000) is a IMX [   
0.310177] 30890000.serial: ttymxc1 at MMIO 0x30890000 (irq = 31, base_baud = 1500000) is a IMX [    1.339368] printk: console [ttymxc1] enabled [    1.350162] imx-lcdifv3 32fc6000.lcd-controller: No irq get [    1.359106] imx-hdmi-pavi 32fc4000.hdmi-pai-pvi: No pvi clock get [
1.536802] loop: module loaded [    1.548156] imx ahci driver is registered. [    1.556012] spi_imx 30830000.spi: probed [    1.561184] spi-nor spi1.0: n25q256ax1 (32768 Kbytes) [    1.569951] libphy: Fixed MDIO Bus: probed [    1.574869] tun: Universal TUN/TAP device driver,
1.6 [    1.581014] thunder_xcv, ver 1.0 [    1.584288] thunder_bgx, ver 1.0 [    1.587545] nicpf, ver 1.0 [    1.591226] pps pps0: new PPS source ptp0 [    1.600178] libphy: fec_enet_mii_bus: probed [   
1.605486] fec 30be0000.ethernet eth0: registered PHC device 0 [    1.612307] Freescale FM module, FMD API version 21.1.0 [    1.617943] Freescale FM Ports module [    1.621616] fsl_mac: fsl_mac: FSL FMan MAC API based driver [    1.627434] fsl_dpa: FSL DPAA Ethernet driver [    1.631994] fsl_advanced: FSL DPAA Advanced drivers: [    1.636970] fsl_proxy: FSL DPAA Proxy initialization driver [    1.642711] fsl_oh: FSL FMan Offline Parsing port driver [    1.649214] hclge is initializing [    1.652541] hns3: Hisilicon Ethernet Network Driver for Hip08 Family - version [    1.659769] hns3: Copyright (c) 2017 Huawei Corporation. [    1.665128] e1000: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - version 7.3.21-k8-NAPI [    1.672184] e1000: Copyright (c) 1999-2006 Intel Corporation. [    1.677968] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 3.2.6-k [    1.683804] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2015 Intel Corporation. [    1.689764] igb: Intel(R) Gigabit Ethernet Network Driver - version 5.6.0-k [    1.696736] igb: Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Intel Corporation. [    1.702346] igbvf: Intel(R) Gigabit Virtual Function Network Driver - version 2.4.0-k [    1.710180] igbvf: Copyright (c) 2009 - 2012 Intel Corporation. [    1.716326] sky2: driver version 1.30 [    1.720819] imx-dwmac 30bf0000.ethernet: no reset control found [    1.726901] imx-dwmac 30bf0000.ethernet: User ID: 0x10, Synopsys ID: 0x51 [    1.733706] imx-dwmac 30bf0000.ethernet:     DWMAC4/5 [    1.738533] imx-dwmac 30bf0000.ethernet: DMA HW capability register supported [    1.745683] imx-dwmac 30bf0000.ethernet: RX Checksum Offload Engine supported [   
1.752828] imx-dwmac 30bf0000.ethernet: TX Checksum insertion supported [    1.759536] imx-dwmac 30bf0000.ethernet: Wake-Up On Lan supported [
1.765665] imx-dwmac 30bf0000.ethernet: Enable RX Mitigation via HW Watchdog Timer [    1.773336] imx-dwmac 30bf0000.ethernet: Enabled Flow TC (entries=8) [    1.779701] imx-dwmac 30bf0000.ethernet: Enabling HW TC (entries=256, max_off=256) [    1.787404] libphy: stmmac: probed [    1.793009] VFIO - User Level meta-driver version:
0.3 [    1.800529] dwc3 38100000.dwc3: Failed to get clk 'ref': -2 [    1.807170] dwc3 38200000.dwc3: Failed to get clk 'ref': -2 [    1.814544] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver [    1.821089] ehci-pci: EHCI PCI platform driver [    1.825575] ehci-platform: EHCI generic platform driver [    1.831076] ohci_hcd: USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver [    1.837283] ohci-pci: OHCI PCI platform driver [    1.841764] ohci-platform: OHCI generic platform driver [    1.847887] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage [    1.853967] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial_generic [    1.860518] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for generic [    1.866554] usbcore: registered new interface driver ftdi_sio [    1.872323] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for FTDI USB Serial Device [    1.879664] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb_serial_simple [    1.886214] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for carelink [    1.892327] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for zio [    1.898009] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for funsoft [    1.904037] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for flashloader [   
1.910411] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for google [    1.916354] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for libtransistor [    1.922908] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for vivopay [    1.928936] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for moto_modem [    1.935225] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for motorola_tetra [    1.941865] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for novatel_gps [    1.948238] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for hp4x [    1.954010] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for suunto [    1.959951] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for siemens_mpi [    1.969888] input: 30370000.snvs:snvs-powerkey as /devices/platform/soc@0/30000000.bus/30370000.snvs/30370000.snvs:snvs-powerkey/input/input0 [    1.984954] snvs_rtc 30370000.snvs:snvs-rtc-lp: registered as rtc0 [    1.991282] i2c /dev entries driver [    2.004605] imx2-wdt
30280000.watchdog: timeout 60 sec (nowayout=0) [    2.011262] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3 [    2.015723] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered [    2.020870] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCSP registered [    2.026205] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol LL registered [    2.031350] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol ATH3K registered [    2.036771] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered [    2.043152] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Broadcom registered [    2.048844] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol QCA registered [    2.054153] EDAC MC: ECC not enabled [    2.059812] failed to register cpuidle driver [    2.064540] sdhci: Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver [    2.070731] sdhci: Copyright(c) Pierre Ossman [    2.075352] Synopsys Designware Multimedia Card Interface Driver [    2.082295] sdhci-pltfm: SDHCI platform and OF driver helper [    2.088789] mmc0: CQHCI version 5.10 [    2.123455] mmc0: SDHCI controller on 30b40000.mmc [30b40000.mmc] using ADMA [    2.130941] mmc1: CQHCI version 5.10 [    2.135030] mmc2: CQHCI version 5.10 [   
2.169737] mmc2: SDHCI controller on 30b60000.mmc [30b60000.mmc] using ADMA [    2.179271] ledtrig-cpu: registered to indicate activity on CPUs [    2.187178] caam 30900000.crypto: device ID = 0x0a16040100000100 (Era 9) [    2.194003] caam 30900000.crypto: job rings = 3, qi = 0 [    2.214322] caam algorithms registered in /proc/crypto [    2.221185] caam 30900000.crypto: caam pkc algorithms registered in /proc/crypto [    2.230722] caam_jr 30901000.jr: registering rng-caam [    2.240783] caam-snvs 30370000.caam-snvs: violation handlers armed - non-secure state [    2.249304] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid [    2.254909] usbhid: USB HID core driver [    2.259004] mxc-md 32c00000.bus:camera: deferring cap_device device registration [    2.267986] mxc-isi 32e00000.isi: mxc_isi.0 registered successfully [    2.275143] mxc-mipi-csi2-sam 32e40000.csi: 32e40000.csi supply mipi-phy not found, using dummy regulator [    2.284990] mxc-mipi-csi2-sam 32e40000.csi: lanes: 2, hs_settle: 13, clk_settle: 2, wclk: 1, freq: 500000000 [    2.296038] No fsl,qman node [    2.298923] Freescale USDPAA process driver [   
2.303114] fsl-usdpaa: no region found [    2.306954] Freescale USDPAA process IRQ driver [    2.318329] Galcore version 6.4.0.234062 [   
2.438453] hantrodec 0 : module inserted. Major = 236 [    2.444207] hantrodec 1 : module inserted. Major = 236 [    2.451460] hantroenc: HW at base <0000000038320000> with ID <0x80006200> [    2.458410] hx280enc: module inserted. Major <235> [    2.475542] fsl-micfil-dai 30ca0000.micfil: GET IRQ: 50 [    2.480802] fsl-micfil-dai 30ca0000.micfil: GET IRQ: 51 [    2.481713] mmc2: Command Queue Engine enabled [    2.486054] fsl-micfil-dai 30ca0000.micfil: GET IRQ: 52 [  
2.490503] mmc2: new HS400 Enhanced strobe MMC card at address 0001 [    2.495729] fsl-micfil-dai 30ca0000.micfil: GET IRQ: 53 [    2.502558] mmcblk2: mmc2:0001 DG4032 29.1 GiB [    2.510665] imx-wm8960 sound-wm8960: failed to find codec platform device [    2.512024] mmcblk2boot0: mmc2:0001 DG4032 partition 1 4.00 MiB [    2.520763] debugfs: Directory '30ca0000.micfil' with parent 'imx-audio-micfil' already present! [    2.524703] mmcblk2boot1: mmc2:0001 DG4032 partition 2 4.00 MiB [    2.533426] imx-micfil sound-micfil: snd-soc-dummy-dai <-> 30ca0000.micfil mapping ok [    2.539388] mmcblk2rpmb: mmc2:0001 DG4032 partition 3 4.00 MiB, chardev (237:0) [ 
2.547107] imx-micfil sound-micfil: ASoC: no DMI vendor name! [    2.555502]  mmcblk2: p1 p2 [    2.561177] imx-cdnhdmi sound-hdmi: ASoC: failed to init link imx8 hdmi: -517 [    2.570203] imx-cdnhdmi sound-hdmi: snd_soc_register_card failed (-517) [    2.577251] debugfs: Directory '30cc0000.xcvr' with parent 'imx-audio-xcvr' already present! [    2.585782] imx-xcvr sound-xcvr: snd-soc-dummy-dai <-> 30cc0000.xcvr mapping ok [    2.593108] imx-xcvr sound-xcvr: ASoC: no DMI vendor name! [    2.599033] pktgen: Packet Generator for packet performance testing. Version: 2.75 [    2.606972] NET: Registered protocol family 26 [    2.611996] NET: Registered protocol family 10 [
2.617138] Segment Routing with IPv6 [    2.620865] NET: Registered protocol family 17 [    2.625382] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized [    2.630274] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized [    2.635438] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11 [    2.639199] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3 [    2.644514] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast [    2.649748] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized [    2.654718] Bluetooth: HIDP (Human Interface Emulation) ver 1.2 [    2.660647] Bluetooth: HIDP socket layer initialized [    2.665650] 8021q: 802.1Q VLAN Support v1.8 [   
2.669851] lib80211: common routines for IEEE802.11 drivers [    2.675615] 9pnet: Installing 9P2000 support [    2.679916] tsn generic netlink module v1 init... [    2.684680] Key type dns_resolver registered [    2.689270] registered taskstats version 1 [   
2.693378] Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates [    2.699291] Key type encrypted registered [    2.727463] pca9450 0-0025: Device ID=0x31 [    2.731578] pca9450 0-0025: gpio_intr = 3 [    2.735614] pca9450 0-0025: chip_irq=85 [    2.758372] random: fast init done [   
2.769865] i2c i2c-0: IMX I2C adapter registered [    2.775284] adv7511 1-003d: 1-003d supply avdd not found, using dummy regulator [   
2.782653] adv7511 1-003d: 1-003d supply dvdd not found, using dummy regulator [    2.790009] adv7511 1-003d: 1-003d supply pvdd not found, using dummy regulator [    2.797361] adv7511 1-003d: 1-003d supply a2vdd not found, using dummy regulator [    2.804800] adv7511 1-003d: 1-003d supply v3p3 not found, using dummy regulator [    2.812166] adv7511 1-003d: 1-003d supply v1p2 not found, using dummy regulator [ 
2.820052] adv7511 1-003d: Probe failed. Remote port 'mipi_dsi@32e60000' disabled [    2.881374] it6263 1-004c: Probe failed. Remote port 'lvds-channel@0' disabled [    2.890046] ov5640 1-003c: 1-003c supply DOVDD not found, using dummy regulator [   
2.897411] ov5640 1-003c: 1-003c supply AVDD not found, using dummy regulator [    2.904674] ov5640 1-003c: 1-003c supply DVDD not found, using dummy regulator [    2.955192] ov5640 1-003c: ov5640_read_reg: error: reg=300a [    2.960781] ov5640 1-003c: ov5640_check_chip_id: failed to read chip identifier [    2.968246] i2c i2c-1: IMX I2C adapter registered [    2.981786] i2c i2c-2: IMX I2C adapter registered [    2.987272] imx8mq-usb-phy 381f0040.usb-phy: 381f0040.usb-phy supply vbus not found, using dummy regulator [   
2.997172] imx8mq-usb-phy 382f0040.usb-phy: 382f0040.usb-phy supply vbus not found, using dummy regulator [    3.009137] pwm-backlight lvds_backlight: lvds_backlight supply power not found, using dummy regulator [    3.009324] imx6q-pcie 33800000.pcie: 33800000.pcie supply epdev_on not found, using dummy regulator [    3.023713] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013). [    3.027865] imx6q-pcie 33800000.pcie: host bridge /pcie@33800000 ranges: [   
3.034241] [drm] No driver support for vblank timestamp query. [    3.040948] imx6q-pcie 33800000.pcie:   No bus range found for /pcie@33800000, using [bus 00-ff] [    3.046932] imx-drm display-subsystem: bound imx-lcdifv3-crtc.0 (ops lcdifv3_crtc_ops) [  
3.055661] imx6q-pcie 33800000.pcie:    IO 0x1ff80000..0x1ff8ffff -> 0x00000000 [    3.063611] imx-drm display-subsystem: bound imx-lcdifv3-crtc.1 (ops lcdifv3_crtc_ops) [    3.070977] imx6q-pcie
33800000.pcie:   MEM 0x18000000..0x1fefffff -> 0x18000000 [    3.078927] imx-drm display-subsystem: bound imx-lcdifv3-crtc.2 (ops lcdifv3_crtc_ops) [    3.086341] imx6q-pcie 33800000.pcie: PLL REF_CLK is used!. [    3.094789] imx_sec_dsim_drv 32e60000.mipi_dsi: version number is 0x1060200 [    3.106785] imx_sec_dsim_drv 32e60000.mipi_dsi: Failed to attach bridge: 32e60000.mipi_dsi [    3.115062] imx_sec_dsim_drv 32e60000.mipi_dsi: failed to bind sec dsim bridge:
-19 [    3.122732] imx-drm display-subsystem: bound 32e60000.mipi_dsi (ops imx_sec_dsim_ops) [    3.130614] imx-drm display-subsystem: bound 32c00000.bus:ldb@32ec005c (ops imx8mp_ldb_ops) [    3.139034] dwhdmi-imx 32fd8000.hdmi: No pavi info found [    3.144367] imx-drm display-subsystem: failed to bind 32fd8000.hdmi (ops dw_hdmi_imx_ops):
-517 [    3.153184] imx-drm display-subsystem: master bind failed: -517 [    3.160696] dwc3 38100000.dwc3: Failed to get clk 'ref': -2 [    3.166397] OF: graph: no port node found in /usb-phy@381f0040 [    3.173490] dwc3 38200000.dwc3: Failed to get clk 'ref': -2 [    3.179426] xhci-hcd xhci-hcd.1.auto: xHCI Host Controller [    3.184942] xhci-hcd xhci-hcd.1.auto: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1 [    3.192944] xhci-hcd xhci-hcd.1.auto: hcc params 0x0220fe6c hci version 0x110 quirks 0x0000000001810010 [    3.202386] xhci-hcd xhci-hcd.1.auto: irq 78, io mem 0x38200000 [    3.208304] imx6q-pcie 33800000.pcie: PCIe PLL locked after 0 us. [    3.214989] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found [    3.218773] hub 1-0:1.0: 1 port detected [    3.222943] xhci-hcd xhci-hcd.1.auto: xHCI Host Controller [   
3.228445] xhci-hcd xhci-hcd.1.auto: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2 [    3.236138] xhci-hcd xhci-hcd.1.auto: Host supports USB 3.0 SuperSpeed [    3.242720] usb usb2: We don't know the algorithms for LPM for this host, disabling LPM. [    3.251183] hub 2-0:1.0: USB hub found [    3.254960] hub 2-0:1.0: 1 port detected [  
3.260140] imx-cpufreq-dt imx-cpufreq-dt: cpu speed grade 5 mkt segment 0 supported-hw 0x20 0x1 [    3.275980] mmc1: CQHCI version 5.10 [   
3.279598] sdhci-esdhc-imx 30b50000.mmc: Got CD GPIO [    3.308361] imx6q-pcie 33800000.pcie: Link up [    3.312740] imx6q-pcie
33800000.pcie: Link up [    3.316060] mmc1: SDHCI controller on 30b50000.mmc [30b50000.mmc] using ADMA [    3.317109] imx6q-pcie
33800000.pcie: Link up, Gen1 [    3.325750] mx8-img-md: Registered mxc_isi.0.capture as /dev/video0 [    3.329146] imx6q-pcie
33800000.pcie: PCI host bridge to bus 0000:00 [    3.335558] unregister ISI channel: mxc_isi.0 [    3.341691] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [bus 00-ff] [    3.351532] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [io  0x0000-0xffff] [    3.355241] debugfs: Directory '30c30000.sai' with parent 'wm8960-audio' already present! [   
3.357720] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x18000000-0x1fefffff] [    3.357742] pci 0000:00:00.0: [16c3:abcd] type 01 class 0x060400 [    3.366018] debugfs: Directory '30c90000.easrc' with parent 'wm8960-audio' already present! [   
3.372795] pci 0000:00:00.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0x00000000-0x000fffff] [    3.378863] imx-wm8960 sound-wm8960: wm8960-hifi <-> 30c30000.sai mapping ok [    3.387142] pci 0000:00:00.0: reg 0x38: [mem 0x00000000-0x0000ffff pref] [    3.395090] imx-wm8960 sound-wm8960: snd-soc-dummy-dai <-> 30c90000.easrc mapping ok [    3.400505] pci 0000:00:00.0: supports D1 [    3.407260] imx-wm8960 sound-wm8960: wm8960-hifi <-> 30c30000.sai mapping ok [    3.414907] pci 0000:00:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D1 D3hot D3cold [    3.417132] pci 0000:01:00.0: [1b4b:2b42] type 00 class 0x020000 [    3.418988] imx-wm8960 sound-wm8960: ASoC: no DMI vendor name! [    3.426035] pci 0000:01:00.0: MSI quirk detected; MSI disabled [    3.450010] pci 0000:01:00.0: quirk_disable_all_msi+0x0/0x30 took 23406 usecs [   
3.457291] pci 0000:01:00.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0x00000000-0x000fffff 64bit pref] [    3.464584] pci 0000:01:00.0: reg 0x18: [mem 0x00000000-0x000fffff 64bit pref] [    3.472409] pci 0000:01:00.0: supports D1 D2 [    3.476684] pci 0000:01:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D1 D3hot D3cold [    3.483277] pci 0000:01:00.0: 2.000 Gb/s available PCIe bandwidth, limited by 2.5 GT/s x1 link at 0000:00:00.0 (capable of 4.000 Gb/s with 5 GT/s x1 link) [    3.493662] mmc1: host does not support reading read-only switch, assuming write-enable [    3.509847] pci 0000:00:00.0: BAR 0: assigned [mem 0x18000000-0x180fffff] [   
3.516732] pci 0000:00:00.0: BAR 15: assigned [mem 0x18100000-0x182fffff pref] [    3.524063] pci 0000:00:00.0: BAR 6: assigned [mem 0x18300000-0x1830ffff pref] [    3.531304] pci 0000:01:00.0: BAR 0: assigned [mem 0x18100000-0x181fffff 64bit pref] [
3.539127] pci 0000:01:00.0: BAR 2: assigned [mem 0x18200000-0x182fffff 64bit pref] [    3.547138] pci 0000:00:00.0: PCI bridge to [bus 01-ff] [    3.552383] pci 0000:00:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0x18100000-0x182fffff pref] [    3.553646] imx-cdnhdmi sound-hdmi: ASoC: failed to init link imx8 hdmi: -517 [    3.559916] pcieport 0000:00:00.0: PME: Signaling with IRQ 244 [    3.566779] imx-cdnhdmi sound-hdmi: snd_soc_register_card failed (-517) [    3.591087] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013). [    3.597728] [drm] No driver support for vblank timestamp query. [    3.603705] imx-drm display-subsystem: bound imx-lcdifv3-crtc.0 (ops lcdifv3_crtc_ops) [    3.611644] imx-drm display-subsystem: bound imx-lcdifv3-crtc.1 (ops lcdifv3_crtc_ops) [    3.619604] imx-drm display-subsystem: bound imx-lcdifv3-crtc.2 (ops lcdifv3_crtc_ops) [  
3.633774] imx_sec_dsim_drv 32e60000.mipi_dsi: version number is 0x1060200 [    3.642782] imx_sec_dsim_drv 32e60000.mipi_dsi: Failed to attach bridge: 32e60000.mipi_dsi [    3.652174] imx_sec_dsim_drv 32e60000.mipi_dsi: failed to bind sec dsim bridge: -19 [    3.660881] imx-drm display-subsystem: bound 32e60000.mipi_dsi (ops imx_sec_dsim_ops) [    3.670878] imx-drm display-subsystem: bound 32c00000.bus:ldb@32ec005c (ops imx8mp_ldb_ops) [    3.681358] mmc1: new ultra high speed SDR104 SDHC card at address 0001 [    3.688294] dwhdmi-imx 32fd8000.hdmi: Detected HDMI TX controller v2.13a with HDCP (samsung_dw_hdmi_phy2) [    3.698024] mmcblk1: mmc1:0001 GB1QT 29.8 GiB [    3.703192] dwhdmi-imx 32fd8000.hdmi: registered DesignWare HDMI I2C bus driver [    3.710530]  mmcblk1: p1 p2 [    3.714539] imx-drm display-subsystem: bound 32fd8000.hdmi (ops dw_hdmi_imx_ops) [
3.722131] [drm] Initialized imx-drm 1.0.0 20120507 for display-subsystem on minor 0 [    3.729996] [drm] Cannot find any crtc or sizes [    3.735260] debugfs: Directory '30cb0000.aud2htx' with parent 'audio-hdmi' already present! [    3.743672] imx-cdnhdmi sound-hdmi: i2s-hifi <-> 30cb0000.aud2htx mapping ok [    3.750739] imx-cdnhdmi sound-hdmi: ASoC: no DMI vendor name! [    3.756553] [drm] Cannot find any crtc or sizes [    3.762190] snvs_rtc
30370000.snvs:snvs-rtc-lp: setting system clock to 1970-01-01T00:00:01 UTC (1) [    3.771818] isi-m2m 32e00000.isi:m2m_device: Register m2m success for ISI.0 [    3.778904] cfg80211: Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates for regulatory database [    3.788423] cfg80211: Loaded X.509 cert 'sforshee: 00b28ddf47aef9cea7' [    3.795017] platform regulatory.0: Direct firmware load for regulatory.db failed with error
-2 [    3.803640] platform regulatory.0: Falling back to sysfs fallback for: regulatory.db [    3.816929] ALSA device list: [   
3.819906]   #0: imx-audio-micfil [    3.823308]   #1: imx-audio-xcvr [    3.826541]   #2: wm8960-audio [    3.829602]   #3: audio-hdmi [    3.837644] EXT4-fs (mmcblk1p2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null) [    3.845784] VFS: Mounted root (ext4 filesystem) on device 179:98. [    3.852502] devtmpfs: error mounting -2 [   
3.857063] Freeing unused kernel memory: 2944K [    3.861697] Run /sbin/init as init process [    3.865829] Run /etc/init as init process [    3.869864] Run /bin/init as init process [    3.873914] Run /bin/sh as init process [    3.877831] Kernel panic - not syncing: No working init found.  Try passing init= option to kernel. See Linux Documentation/admin-guide/init.rst for guidance. [    3.891999] CPU: 1 PID: 1 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 5.4.24-gbabac008e #1 [    3.898871] Hardware name: NXP i.MX8MPlus EVK board (DT) [    3.904181] Call trace: [    3.906631]  dump_backtrace+0x0/0x140 [    3.910293]  show_stack+0x14/0x20 [    3.913608]  dump_stack+0xb4/0xf8 [   
3.916923]  panic+0x158/0x324 [    3.919977]  kernel_init+0xec/0x100 [    3.923466]  ret_from_fork+0x10/0x18 [    3.927042] SMP: stopping secondary CPUs [    3.930964] Kernel Offset: disabled [    3.934452] CPU features: 0x0002,2000200c [    3.938459] Memory Limit: none [   
3.941517] ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: No working init found.  Try passing init= option to kernel. See Linux Documentation/admin-guide/init.rst for guidance. ]---
```

Answer (score 1):

Kernel complains that it did not find init. Did you specify a root filesystem in uboot boot command? Or an initramfs?

At some point during it's initialization, kernel starts 'init' from such rootfs, initrd or initramfs. Usually, this is /init or /sbin/init. It can also now start systemd init.

The task started here gets PID 1. If pid 1 exits, kernel panics. So make sure you pass a valid FS to your kernel. We can help you further if you tell us more details about your uboot end and the binaries you want to start.